# Configure IE mode for Microsoft Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, compatibility

I've collected site discovery XML files for IE mode for Edge, and compiled them into a site discovery XML file.  Once I've opened it in the MS online tool for configuring IE mode for Edge, there are over 88,000 URLs.  After selecting "Remove non-issue sites", I'm down to 47k sites.

When I click on "Not configured" it says to open the site in Edge and then in IE mode and compare the results.  It seems that this wants me to address each URL one at a time, despite the fact that you can obviously bulk configure them.  I've been searching Google, but I haven't really found a good rule of thumb for bulk configuring.  For example, if I filter down to compatibly detection "ActiveX Control", would it be best to select all sites and bulk "Set to IE Mode"? Or for "X-UA Compatibility"?

I haven't been able to find a chart or any type of best practice for bulk setting the various sites.

[Compatibility Detections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13chq.png)

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: I'm not sure what is the `MS online tool` you mentioned, can you describe it more clearly? And as far as I know, you can configure IE mode site list via these two methods: `Internet Explorer mode pages` list in path `edge://settings/defaultBrowser`, and the other one is [Configure IE mode policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies) via group policy. In addition, I recommend that you refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/browsers/development-website/ie-document-modes-faq) as appropriate.

Comment: The URL I'm using to try to parse the DiscoveredSites.XML is https://assistants.microsoft.com/configureiemode#/modernonboarding/configureiemode

Comment: Well, I think it mostly depends on your needs. You need to filter them to see if the sites in the list have meta tag with X-UA-Compatible, or whether they use ActiveX controls.